# black displacement artifacts using micro-displacement and adaptive subdivision

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, subdivision-surface, displacement

I am currently using micro-displacement along side with adaptive subdivision.

However I have stumble upon a weird artifact.

[image: weird displacement artifacts]

As you can see there are some black pixelated artifacts along side the crevices.

This is my node setup:

[image: displacement node setup]

Do note that I'm using Remington's PBR shader.

Because of my current reputation I cannot post more images, I hope these are enough information to help me solve the problem

Best Regards,

Lukas

** The brick texture is from polligon along side with the gloss, normal and displacement maps.

Comment: Do you get the same black artifacts if you plug the bump map directly into the output node?

Comment: In my experience this isn't an artifact, it's just there isn't enough geometry, and the 'artifacts' are just shadowed faces. Try turning the resolution up?